# Java compiler super() constructor generals

Tags: java, class, inheritance, compiler-construction, constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use of ‘super’ keyword when accessing non-overridden superclass methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803346/use-of-super-keyword-when-accessing-non-overridden-superclass-methods)

I'm new to Java and have been reading a lot about it lately to get more knowledge and experience about the language. I have a question about inherited methods and extending classes when the compiler inserts automatic code.

I've been reading that if I create class A with some methods including lets say a method called `checkDuePeriod()`, and then create a class B which extends class A and its methods.

If I then call the method `checkDuePeriod()` within class B without using the `super.checkDuePeriod()` syntax, during compilation will the compiler include the `super.` before `checkDuePeriod()` or will the fact that the compiler includes the `super()` constructor automatically when compiling the class imply the `super.` call of the methods that class B calls from class A?

I'm a little confused about this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This thread might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803346/use-of-super-keyword-when-accessing-non-overridden-superclass-methods

Comment: What do constructors have to do with your question?

Answer (score 5):

The super class's implementation of regular methods is *not* automatically invoked in sub classes, but a form of the super class's constructor must be called in a sub class's constructor.

In some cases, the call to `super()` is implied, such as when the super class has a default (no-parameter) constructor.  However, if no default constructor exists in the super class, the sub class's constructors must invoke a super class constructor directly or indirectly.

Default constructor example:

```
public class A {
    public A() {
        // default constructor for A
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    public B() {
        super(); // this call is unnecessary; the compiler will add it implicitly
    }
}
```

Super class without default constructor:

```
public class A {
    public A(int i) {
        // only constructor present has a single int parameter
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    public B() {
        // will not compile without direct call to super(int)!
        super(100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you call `checkDuePeriod()` in B without `super.`, means you want to invoke the method that belongs to the this instance (represented by `this` within B) of B. So, it equivalent to saying `this.checkDuePeriod()`, so it just doesn't make sense for the compiler to add `super.` in the front.

`super.` is something that you must explicitly add to tell the compiler that you want to call the A's version of the method (it is required specially in case B has overridden the implementation provided by A for the method).

Answer (score 1):

Call of super() as a default constructor (constructor with no args) can be direct or non direct but it **garants that fields of extendable class are properly initialized**.

for example:

```
public class A {
    StringBuilder sb;
    public A() {
        sb = new StringBuilder();
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    public B() {
        //the default constructor is called automatically
    }
    public void someMethod(){
        //sb was not initialized in B class, 
        //but we can use it, because java garants that it was initialized
        //and has non null value
        sb.toString();
    }
}
```

But in case of methods:

Methods implement some logic. And if we need to rewrite logic of super class we use

```
public class B extends A {
    public B() {
    }
    public boolean checkDuePeriod(){
       //new check goes here
    }
}
```

and if we want just implement some extra check, using the value returned from checkDuePeriod() of superclass we should do something like this

```
public class B extends A {
    public B() {
    }
    public boolean checkDuePeriod(){
       if(super.checkDuePeriod()){
            //extra check goes here
       }else{
            //do something else if need
       }
       return checkResult;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First about the `Constructors`**:**

**-** When ever an `object` of a class is created, its `constructor` is initialized and **at that time immediately** the `constructor` of its s`uper-class` is called till the `Object` class,

**-** In this process all the instance variables are declared and initialized.

**-** Consider this scenario.

**Dog** is a `sub-class` of **Canine** and Canine is a `sub-class` of **Animal**

Now when Dog object is initialized, before the object actually forms, the Canine class object must be form, and before Canine object can form the Animal class object is to be formed, and before that Object class object must be form,

**So the sequence of object formed is:**

`Object ---> Animal ---> Canine ---> Dog`

So the `Constructor of the Super-Class is Called before the Sub-Class`.

Now with the `Method`**:**

`The most specific version of the method that class is called.`

**Eg:**

```
public class A{

  public void go(){


  }

}

class B extends A{



   public static void main(String[] args){

   new B().go();  // As B has not overridden the go() method of its super class,
           // so the super-class implementation of the go() will be working here
    }
}
```